# Choosing Between Intents(Button Clicks) - Android App Development

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-button

I am new to Android application development, and I've been working on a simple FlashLight app that switches between various colors on the screen. The initial activity draws up a layout with only 2 buttons, labeled Green and Blue. I've installed Click Listeners on both buttons and set intents on them both in order for each to load it's corresponding activity, but when I run the app I can only go from the first view to ONE of the other views(Green OR Blue, but not both). I want to be able to choose EITHER button and load the next activity, but I'm a bit lost. Maybe create a boolean that determines which button the user clicked? IDK. This may sound a bit confusing as I'm not good at describing technical things like this, but here's my code below.

```
package com.jbsoft.SimpleFlashlight;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleFlashLightActivity extends Activity {

  Button GreenButton;
  Button BlueButton;


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BlueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
    BlueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent blueintent = new Intent(SimpleFlashLightActivity.this,
                                       BlueFlashLightActivity.class);
        startActivity(blueintent);

        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "SWITCH COLOR!",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        GreenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
        GreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent greenintent = new Intent(
              SimpleFlashLightActivity.this,
              GreenFlashLightActivty.class);
            startActivity(greenintent);

          }
        });
      }
    });

  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: why have you put the green buttons listener inside the blue's listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the onclicklistener for the greenbutton in the onclick event of the bluebotton. so the listener gets set only once the user clicks the bluebotton. or am i missing something here?

set the onclick listener for the greenbutton outside of the listnere for the bluebutton and it should work..

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Apparently I had my listeners for all 3 of my activities in the wrong place, in this case I had them inside previous onclick events..that was the culprit. Thanks again!